# S3 boto3 list keys after a timestamp in metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to list all keys in an S3 bucket that were modified after a certain timestamp using boto3.

I made these functions but performance is quite slow for buckets with several keys.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
         aws_access_key_id=s3_cred.ACCESS_KEY,
         aws_secret_access_key= s3_cred.SECRET_KEY)

my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

def meta_df(bucket):
    key = []
    ts = []
    for o in bucket.objects.all():
        key.append(o.key)
        ts.append(o.last_modified)
    return pd.DataFrame({'key':key,'ts':ts})


def get_after_timestamp(bucket,ts):
    df = meta_df(bucket)
    df = df[df['ts']>ts]
    return df['key'].tolist()

get_after_timestamp(my_bucket,'2018-09-24 13:39:00')
```

Is there a way to do this in boto3 or in a more performant manner?

Comment: How many objects are in the bucket? How slow is "quite slow"? Is this going to be run often, or just occasionally?

Comment: about 500k Json files. 10 KB each. It needs to run often. Say every 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily list of the objects in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Thus, you would simply need to parse the list rather than make API calls to list the objects. However, the listing is only daily at best, so this depends whether you need the most up-to-date information.

**Update:**

Since you have 500k objects that you want to scan every 5 minutes, you will need a **different approach**. This is because scanning that many files (where each API call only retrieves 1000 objects at a time) will be slow and inefficient.

Instead, you should:

- Create an **S3 Event** on the bucket that triggers a Lambda function whenever a new object is uploaded
- The **Lambda function** stores details of the object in a database (eg DynamoDB)
- Instead of scanning S3 every 5 minutes, consult the database for a list of objects

Some examples are:

- [Building and Maintaining an Amazon S3 Metadata Index without Servers | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/)
- [Using AWS Lambda with S3 and DynamoDB - MicroPyramid](https://micropyramid.com/blog/using-aws-lambda-with-s3-and-dynamodb/)

Comment: Added an alternative method using a S3 trigger and Lambda.